# Get result from activity that launched by widget.

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to use `onActivityResult` in widget that launch activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider implements
    OnActivityResultListener {
Context context;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    this.context = context;
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 1);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.activity_main);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageButton1, pending);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

}
```

I need that when I select contact can get result on the widget

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, add a new intent filter in your appwidget's broadcast and add a personnal action to it like "GET_RESULT_FROM_ACTIVITY", then launch your activity from which you want result. when you are done with your code, call sendBroadcast(your_intent) method in this activity with an intent in which you put your extras and on which you set your action "GET_RESULT_FROM_ACTIVITY". In your onReceive() method of your appwidget, check if intent.getAction().equals("GET_RESULT_FROM_ACTIVITY") and do what you want in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you passed data back from the second activity via `Intent.putExtra()`, you can access whatever you're passing by calling `data.getExtras()` in your `onActivityResult` method.

See tutorial [here.](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12204/onactivityresult-android-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong that because AppWidgetProvider has not the method onActivityResult.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    }
```

IF you want to get result from an activity,you can use send Broadcast to update the appwidget views